# Exporting functions from DLLs, LoadLibrary() needs the string cast with TEXT to compile without error

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I'm learning to write and use DLLs and this is my first attempt at exporting a function from my dll. It works, but this line is what gave me trouble and what I've been able to find regarding the TEXT cast for UNICODE and ANSI I think I need some guidance. As far as I can find this question has not been asked elsewhere on the site so I apologize if anyone finds what I couldn't.

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll");
```

My initial usage, from a short tutorial on explicit linking gives E0167 and C2664 errors regarding LPCWSTR type

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyDLL.dll"));
```

Casting the string to TEXT solves the problem, though I'm not sure why and would like to know

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibraryA("MyDLL.dll");
```

The line I decided to use in the working example. LoadLibraryA() expands LoadLibrary to accept ANSI rather than Wide, which may be the root of my misunderstanding. Why is this necessary when most examples I find show LoadLibrary("NameOfDLL.dll")?

Why does the string not satisfy the standard LoadLibrary() call?

Comment: See [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes) and [Windows Data Types for Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/windows-data-types-for-strings).

Comment: Actually, the `TEXT` is not a cast, it is a macro that magically makes that string into the correct type (and you're lucky it is a macro).  If it were a cast, your program would have compiled, and unfortunately, that DLL name would be junk, thus `LoadLibrary` would have failed.

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` is itself a macro, too. `LoadLibraryW()` and `LoadLibraryA()` are concrete functions that `LoadLibrary()` maps to depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.  Same with the `TEXT()` macro for defining wide and narrow literals, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadLibrary()` is a preprocessor macro. It maps to either `LoadLibraryW()` or `LoadLibraryA()` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.  `LoadLibraryW()` takes a `const wchar_t*` string as input, while `LoadLibraryA()` takes a `const char *` string instead.

The string literal `"MyDLL.dll"` is a `const char[10]`, which *decays* into a `const char *`.  If `UNICODE` is defined, `LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll")` will fail to compile, as you cannot pass a `const char *` where a `const wchar_t *` is expected.

`TEXT()` is also a preprocessor macro.  If `UNICODE` is defined, it appends an `L` prefix to the specified literal making the literal use `wchar_t`, otherwise no prefix is added and the literal uses `char` instead.

Thus, if `UNICODE` is defined, then `LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyDLL.dll"))` is compiled as `LoadLibraryW(L"MyDLL.dll")`, otherwise it is compiled as `LoadLibraryA("MyDLL.dll")` instead.

A majority of Win32 APIs that deal with textual data have similar `A` and `W` versions, and corresponding `UNICODE`-aware preprocessor macros.  So, when using character/string literals with these APIs, you should always use the `TEXT()` macro.  Otherwise, just use the `A` and `W` APIs directly as needed, depending on the type of textual data you are working with.